# C++: autogenerated(default) copy costructor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

If I declare a class like, (no dynamic memory allocation, no pointer):

```
class A{
  int a,b;
public:
  A();
  A(int,int);
  A& operator=(const A);
};
```

Is it safe not to declare a copy constructor? How does the default copy constructor looks like?

```
A& A::operator=(const A other)
{
   a=other.a;
   b=other.b;
   return *this;
}
```

Even If I do not declare a copy constructor, the default one will be called when I call **operator=()**

---

EDIT:

the default destructor is:

```
A::~A(){}
```

so it's not needed here

Comment: Are you confusing a _copy-constructor_ with a _copy-assignment_ operator?

Comment: No, copy-assignment operator is operator=(), and copy constructor is A::A(A&);

Comment: I see, the copy-constructor is called when a copy is needed as the `other` argument to `operator=`

Comment: You probably want to `A& operator=(const& A);` not `A& operator=(const A);`, they are very different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is that if you need to provide either:

- copy constructor or
- destructor or
- copy assignment operator

then you probably need to provide all three of them. This rule is known as **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.

---

> **I*s it safe not to declare a copy constructor?***

It is safe.

> ***Do you have to for your example case?***

Not really. To be specific the rule of three governs that. Check the linked question for more details on that.

---

> ***How does the default copy constructor looks like?***

I gather this is asking, What does the default copy constructor do.
This is answered in:
**C++03 Standard 12.8 Copying class objects:**
**Para 8:**

> The implicitly-defined copy constructor for class X performs a memberwise copy of its subobjects. The order of copying is the same as the order of initialization of bases and members in a user-defined constructor (see 12.6.2). Each subobject is copied in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> — if the subobject is of class type, the copy constructor for the class is used;
> — if the subobject is an array, each element is copied, in the manner appropriate to the element type;
> — if the subobject is of scalar type, the built-in assignment operator is used.
> Virtual base class subobjects shall be copied only once by the implicitly-defined copy constructor (see 12.6.2).

---

> ***Even If I not declare a copy constructor, the default one will be called when I call `operator=()`***

A copy constructor is invoked only when a copy of the class object needs to be created. This involves copies of objects created while passing to or returning from functions.
Your copy assignment operator passes the object `A` *by value*, this pass by value is achieved by passing a copy of the object through copy constructor and hence the call to copy constructor.
To avoid the copy you need to pass *by reference*:

```
A& A::operator=(const A& other)
```

**Good Read:**
[What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: +1, but I don't think that's enough to answer the question. It's obviously important, but I think the question includes "When do I have to provide *any* of the three? Is not having dynamic memory or pointers enough to prove that I don't need any?".

Comment: @us2012: Updated to be more specific. Hth.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing *copy-constructors* with *copy-assignment* operators. The implicitly generated *copy-constructor* will *copy-construct* each of the members:

```
A::A( A const& source )
  : a( source.a )
  , b( source.b )
{}
```

The implicitly generated *copy-assignment* operator will *copy-assign* each of the members:

```
A& A::operator =( A const& source )
{
    a = source.a;
    b = source.b;
    return *this;
}
```

The *copy-assignment* operator as you defined it in your question takes an `A` by *copy*, so the *copy-constructor* will be called to create the argument passed to `operator=`. Note that the copy may be elided under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
A::A(const A& other) != A& A::operator=(const A other)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class provides `operator=`. Per the rule of three (as @AlokSave says), you should then provide the copy constructor and destructor as well.

The question is, if you're happy with the default-supplied copy constructor, why aren't you happy with the default-supplied copy assignment operator? And if you are, just don't declare `operator=` and let the compiler generate the entire "rule of three" for you.